# Where is the syntax error in this Ruby snippet?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, prawn

Pulling my hair out...

```
Prawn::Document.generate(@targetfile) do |pdf|

  pdf.bounding_box ([80, 510] , :width => 400) do

    pdf.text("hello")

  end

end
```

gives a **syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'** for the "comma" just before **:width => 400**

I tried this with both Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.1 - both give the same error. The only other thing I changed was that I upgraded the prawn version from 1.0 to 2.0 - according to the manual using prawn like this should still be ok though.

Comment: Tip: `width:400` has the same effect, and is easier to type (and, arguably, read).

Answer (score 8):

agree with andrew's answer above.  When using a function call in ruby, you can either have a space with no parenthesis, or parenthesis and no space, but not both.  so:

`pdf.bounding_box([80, 510] , :width => 400)` is ok

`pdf.bounding_box [80, 510] , :width => 400` is also ok

But you can't do a space and a parenthesis.  Now in your case, since you want to chain the result of this to a do/end block, you will have to use the parenthesis, so option 1 is the only way to go.

Comment: To clarify why, `Math.sqrt(1+3) * 4` is `8.0` (`Math.sqrt(1+3)) * 4`); but `Math.sqrt (1 + 3) * 4` is `4.0` (`Math.sqrt((1 + 3) * 4)`). When you write `pdf.bounding_box (x, y)`. However, `,` is not an operator in Ruby, so `(1, 3)` (when not in one of special contexts such as function invocation) is a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 4):

It's because of the space between `bounding_box` and the brackets.